# javascript read a blob without FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am developing an epub reader in js.
My app works on chrome 35 and recent browsers but not  the old ones (ex: safari 5).
I got this error "can't find variable FileReader" which occurs when I attempt to read a Blob.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

I am searching for an alternative to FileReader.
I tried to use FileAPI instead which provides a readAsArrayBuffer method too :

```
var reader = FileAPI;
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob, function(e) {
    console.debug(e);
});
```

but console.debug returns : Object {type: "error", target: Blob, result: undefined, error: "filreader_not_support_BinaryString"}

I found this polyfill : https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader but I avoid using jquery.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have no choice but to try some sort of Flash-based fallback. The one you linked is no longer maintained anyway, and it recommends [this alternative](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie). You really don't have a choice here.

Comment: What kind of browser does support `Blob`s but not `FileReader`?

Comment: @Bergi _"What kind of browser does support Blobs but not FileReader"_ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193605/how-to-updoad-in-old-browsers-ex-safari-5-1-4 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195855/how-to-create-an-arraybuffer-and-data-uri-from-blob-and-file-objects-without-fil

Comment: @Bergi See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239361/where-is-blob-binary-data-stored