# How to upload files in old browsers (Ex. Safari 5.1.4)

Tags: javascript, image, safari, cross-browser, base64

Trying to upload images to website by encoding it to Base64. I have this code that works in new Chrome/Mozzilla/IE11. But it doesn't work in Safari 5.1.4 (Windows)

I can see now that FileReader is not available at safari until version 6.0, So any alternatives to this?

This is the code :

```
<input id="#avatar" type="file" onchange="previewFile()">

<script>
var img;
function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    img = reader.result;
    alert(img)
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
}
<...>

</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in console?

Comment: `FileReader` is not available at safari until version 6.0, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compaibility

Comment: And what should I do now?... target IE8-9 also could be nessery

Comment: What is expected result of retrieving `data URI` representation of uploaded file? To set `img` `src` to uploaded file?

Comment: Save and post to dropbox. If  you asking I'm using meteor. but package FS.collection isn't working at some point at all.

Comment: @PabloAaron See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195855/how-to-create-an-arraybuffer-and-data-uri-from-blob-and-file-objects-without-fil