# How to create an ArrayBuffer and data URI from Blob and File objects without FileReader?

Tags: javascript, blob, fileapi, data-uri, typed-arrays

This Question is related to and inspired by [How to updoad in old browsers (ex Safari 5.1.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193605/how-to-updoad-in-old-browsers-ex-safari-5-1-4)

Given an `<input type="file">` element having a `files` property containing `File` objects which inherit from `Blob`, is it possible to create a `ArrayBuffer` and convert the `ArrayBuffer` to a `data URI` from a `Blob` or `File` object without using `FileReader`?

Approaches have tried so far have been

- create a mock `WebSocket` with `.binaryType` set to `"arraybuffer"`, create a `MessageEvent` with `event.data` set to `File` object; result is `File` object at `onmessage` handler
- set prototype of `File` to `ArrayBuffer`, `Uint8Array`; result is `Uncaught TypeError: Method ArrayBuffer.prototype.byteLength called on incompatible receiver #<ArrayBuffer>()`, `Uncaught TypeError: Method get TypedArray.prototype.byteLength called on incompatible receiver [object Object]()`
- set `File` at `FormData` object, attempt to post request body to `<iframe>`, admittedly not well-conceived; result `Bad Request` at [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca7pNsmVhXpv8Us5v8hE?p=preview)

Expected result: Convert `Blob` and `File` objects to `TypedArray` then to [`data URL`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), or directly to `data URL`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" entype="multipart/form-data" target="binaryFrame">
    <input id="#avatar" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <iframe name="binaryFrame"></iframe>
  <script>
    var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
    input.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, true);
    // see http://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/JVfkt/
    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://mock");
    sock.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    sock.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("sock error", e); // ignore, here
      }

    sock.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("socket message", e.data, e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer);
    };

    function handleFiles(evnet) {
      var file = event.target.files[0];
      sock.dispatchEvent(new MessageEvent("message", {
        data: file
      }));
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file);
      document.forms[0].action = data;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

See also [Display image from blob using javascript and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089732/display-image-from-blob-using-javascript-and-websockets) , [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/) ; interestingly ironic as am now asking similar Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302231/is-there-any-way-to-convert-the-file-to-an-arraybuffer-without-filereader-api ; [`Blob` `.slice()` method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#slice-method-algo) , [`FileReader` `.readAsDataURL()` method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readAsDataURL)

Comment: I don't have safari 5 at hand (btw this browser is deprecated for years users should change it to an up-to-date one ASAP), nor a browser that does support `Blob` objects (or `File`) but doesn't support the `FileReader`. Does it really exists? aren't you looking the wrong way? (one workaround would be to upload the File somewhere and then refetch it with XHR but try to answer these first questions first)

Comment: @Kaiido  _"nor a browser that does support Blob objects (or File) but doesn't support the FileReader. Does it really exists?"_ Do not have access to safari here, either. According to MDN browser compatibility, `<input type="file">` is supported at version 1.0 of safari, `Blob` at 5.1, `FileReader` at 6.0;  `responseType` `"blob"` and `"arraybuffer"` at `XMLHttpRequest` state `"Yes"`. Curious how raw data is actually stored, accessed within `Blob` object?

Comment: Probably an early implementation... Too bad it doesn't support URL.createObjectURL either, otherwise you could have tried something as simple as 
`var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){
  rawData = this.response;
}
xhr.open('get', url)
xhr.send();`. Ps talking about early implementations, you can see that IE9 didn't support TypedArray, but still had one kind through canvas' `imageData` object.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, curious how the process was discussed being implemented, or implemented; that is, accessing raw data stored in `Blob`, or `input.files` object at 1.0-5.1? If `Blob` is an object, the raw data is stored within object, yes? Another way to ask Question would be how to follow algorithm for `FileReader` to create a `FileReader` implementation from scratch using steps in algorithm - without using `FileReader`

Comment: Yes and no : yes the browser have it somewhere, but no, the Blob object doesn't expose its data...

Comment: @Kaiido Is requirement not possible?

Comment: Yes, as I said in first comment, if `<input type="file"/>` is supported, this means that you can send it to a server (e.g using a `<form>`), once done, you can fetch the raw data back using xhr. But it will take longer than the small snippet in previous comment ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, possible using post to `php`, though is it possible by other processes without using `XMLHttpRequest`? See also, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375297 , https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/storage/browser/blob/blob_reader.h

Comment: @Kaiido Is requirement not possible at safari 5.1.4 environment using `javascript` alone without using `FileReader` ? _"The only way to read content from a Blob is to use a  FileReader."_  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_creating_a_URL_to_a_typed_array_using_a_blob

Comment: Read this post please [what-to-use-instead-of-filereader-for-safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734150/what-to-use-instead-of-filereader-for-safari)

Answer (score 2):

I just put it here:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
input.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, true);

// for url
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function handleFiles(evnet) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  document.querySelector('iframe')
    .setAttribute('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="get" entype="multipart/form-data" target="binaryFrame">
    <input id="#avatar" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <iframe name="binaryFrame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```