# Get HTTP Body of Form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, http, post

Is it possible in Javascript to get the contents of the HTTP Body of the resulting HTTP request that would be sent when a Form is submitted?

Say I have a Form of type 'POST' with a file input and some other input fields and an enctype attribute of 'multipart/form-data'. I would like to get the verbatim HTTP Body and possibly HTTP Headers of the request the browser would generate *if* I submitted the form (without actually submitting it).

Comment: It's logically impossible to do something without doing it. You can do something by [doing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Response`, `Response.body.getReader()` which is a `ReadableStream` to read the contents of `FormData` object. Use `TextDecoder` to convert `Uint8Array` to readable text. Note, you cannot read stream and headers from the same `Response` object. Though you can create a new `Response` object from same input data and the read `Headers`

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData();
  var input = e.target.querySelector("input");
  formData.append("file", input.files[0], input.files[0].name);

  var response = new Response(formData);
  var stream = response.body;
  var reader = stream.getReader();
  var decoder = new TextDecoder();
  reader.read()
    .then(function processData(result) {
      if (result.done) {
        console.log("stream done");
        return;
      }
      var data = decoder.decode(result.value);
      console.log(data);

      return reader.read().then(processData);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("catch stream cancellation:", err);
    });

  reader.closed.then(function() {
    console.log("stream closed");
  });
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @user3700562 See also [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) , plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/pLvfJ93R7g5RaezBhz6h?p=preview

Comment: Note, substitute `response.text()` for `stream.getReader()` at Firefox, which does not support `ReadableStream`

Answer (score 2):

No. There are no APIs that expose that information.

You can attempt to manually construct the request, but there's no way to get the browser to prepare it for you.

Comment: It is possible to retrieve `.har` representation of `Request` at `DevTools`. It is also possible to get the `FormData` data

Comment: @guest271314 it's not possible to submit a form without submitting it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes it is. You can create a `Response` object and read the `Response.body`. See this deleted [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38295759/) at [How to create an ArrayBuffer and data URI from Blob and File objects without FileReader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195855/how-to-create-an-arraybuffer-and-data-uri-from-blob-and-file-objects-without-fil)

Comment: @guest271314 — The har representation is (a) only available after the submission and (b) isn't available to JavaScript in the assumed context of "running in a webpage". The deleted answer you mention doesn't deal with the creation of a *Request*.

Comment: @Quentin Believe OP is attempting to read what is being `POST`ed from `<form>`